# Best position to install a bi-metal thermometer

Tags: temperature-control, kettle, temperature-probe

Of course I'm asking about the height. How to calculate the best height to install a bi-metal thermometer like this: [Dial Thermometer - MoreBeer](http://morebeer.com/products/dial-thermometer-3-face-6-probe.html) ?

Usually, we can see it installed in the middle of wort, approximately. But if we mash several volumes, should we calculate the middle of the smallest one ? This wouldn't harm the thermal reading of the largest wort volume ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recently installed a weldless blichmann Brewmometer and reading the specifications for it, it recommended to install it at least 6" of the bottom. This recommended minimum height was not in order for the temperature-probe to always be in the center, or even immersed in the liquid at all times, but to prevent the heat from the stove/cooker "rolling" over the edges of the pot and reaching the thermometer. This will most likely kill your thermometer.

So taking this into account, put the pot onto your stove and start brewing. When you are getting a boil, check to see at what height of the pot you can comfortably hold your hand without having to pull it away; this will be the minimum distance you should place the thermometer at in order not to damage it.

In regards to getting the correct temperature, if you stir your wort to circulate the liquid it should have *roughly* the same temperature no matter where you decide to place it.

Comment: I've been contacting some manufactures, and some say something similar you told, others doesn't matter but inform the "operation temperature" of their products. By the way, I could learn that thermometers have different operation temperatures, according with the their design. So, even manufactures not informing the installation height, I suppose we need to respect the "operation temperature", measuring the external kettle temp to reach a secure point to the thermometer operate without being damaged.